# SqlSave - dates not in order appending to database

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am using the command `sqlSave` (part of the RODBC package) to add data to an existing MS sql database. The original table in the database is ordered by date when I run a simple "SELECT TOP 2000" query (there are only 1500 rows in the table so all data is displayed by this query) but when I run `sqlSave` the new data is added but the table is no longer in date order - some rows are added at the top and some at the bottom.

I am using the following code:

```
sqlSave(channel, Mydataframe, MyTable, append=TRUE, rownames = FALSE, fast = FALSE)
```

The R dataframe has the same number of columns (in the same order and with the same names) as the table.

Comment: I've also noticed that in my databases here that adding querying a table doesn't always result in tables ordered by the sequentially assigned ID.  The thing to remember, however, is that the database is a place to store data.  The order of the rows is inconsequential so long as the data maintain integrity.  If you need your results sorted in a particular way, that should be addressed upon the query (i.e. SELECT) not upon the save.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/

Comment: In order to have a fully qualified query through SQL, it's imperative to specify and order by and assign alias to reserved column names. There is no guarantee that the RS will be identical without an order by.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Tables do not have an order, and unless you specify an ORDER BY in your query, your results are not guaranteed to come out in any particular, consistent order.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. This makes sense now - I will apply the necessary ordering elsewhere.